Python code for subscriptions doesn't show changes
I've been trying to use one of the official subscription examples [1] for Py-Substrate docs and it doesn't update after changes.
def subscription_handler(storage_key, updated_obj, update_nr, subscription_id):
    print(f"Update for {storage_key.params[0]}: {updated_obj.value}")

# Accounts to track
storage_keys = [
    substrate.create_storage_key(
        "System", "Account", ["5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY"]
    ),
    substrate.create_storage_key(
        "System", "Account", ["5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty"]
    )
]

result = substrate.subscribe_storage(
    storage_keys=storage_keys, subscription_handler=subscription_handler
)

The way it works for me seems extremely confusing:

Where do those other values (storage_key, updated_obj, update_nr, subscription_id) come from? Where do values for update_nr, subscription_id come from and what's the use for them? Nothing seems explained in the docs.
That outputs two rows of data and then it blocks. I know it's supposed to ("These subscriptions are blocking until the subscription is closed."), but how are we supposed to "close the subscription"? The only way I know is CTRL + C.

Update for 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY: {'nonce': 17, 'consumers': 0, 'providers': 1, 'sufficients': 0, 'data': {'free': 2039606219, 'reserved': 143258000000, 'misc_frozen': 0, 'fee_frozen': 0}}


While it's blocked, I send a small mount of tokens from one to another address and wait. No updates occur. I expected that when balance or nonce update, the code would spit out two more lines due to updates happening in subscribed addresses.
Even after I press CTRL+C, send tokens from A to B and re-run the last assignment (result=), I still get the exact same values - same nonce, same balance, although on chain I can see changes. I couldn't believe I could not only miss updates, but get outdated values with this example! Is that because some stale subscription ID still exists somewhere?

Is that's how this is supposed to work? I thought new values would be displayed if they change on-chain.
I'd like to subscribe to monitor values like address balance changes, to avoid unnecessarily looping and querying over hundreds of accounts every few minutes.
[1] https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/usage/subscriptions/

Just found this [1] on the same topic and the old example with threads partially works (A->B is registered in the refreshed output of the first address A, but not in the output of second line B. Transfer going from B->A is are not registered at all -  no new lines are emitted whatsoever.
[1] https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface/discussions/326#discussioncomment-5214633

After I exhausted all options, I used exit() to get out of Python, I got 15-20 of those missing events output to console. Maybe one or both of these approaches work, but in what appear to be mysterious ways.

As noted in the comment above, it does work (updates may be delayed if your node is slow), so the remaining part is the docs (update_nr, subscription_id) and how to control "subscription", which is why I'm leaving the question open as I can't answer those by myself.
